# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered:

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to de-serialize an http response content into a known model.
The response contain a field called 'schemaFields' which is a string representation of a json object.
Trying to call replace wouldn't change the outcome > `httpRespContent.Replace(@"\", "");`

The serialization fail with the following error:

> After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: m. Path
> 'schemaFields', line 1, position 19.

call stack:

```
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParsePostValue(Boolean ignoreComments)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
```

The model:

```
public class GetOrganizationResponse : PlainIdResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("bpid")]
    public string Bpid { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("source")]
    public string Source { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("schemaFields")]
    public string SchemaFields { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lastUpdateTime")]
    public string LastUpdateTime;
}
```

Using the Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0.

The code with input:

```
const string schemaFields =
    "{\"main\":{\"city\":[\"city\"],\"state\":[\"state\"],\"country\":[\"country\"],\"zip_code\":[\"\"],\"street_address\":[\"streetAddress\"]},\"system\":{\"name\":[\"orgNameWithSamlDataAndOrganization1\"],\"type\":[\"CUSTOMER\"],\"status\":[\"APPROVED\"],\"description\":[\"description\"],\"member_limit\":[-1]}}";
string httpRespContent = $"{{\"schemaFields\":\"{schemaFields}\", \"versionId\":\"1615130797664\",\"bpid\":\"bpidWithSamlDataAndOrganization1\",\"name\":\"orgNameWithSamlDataAndOrganization1\",\"createdTime\":\"1615130797664\",\"description\":\"description\",\"id\":\"b14b9595-f15b-4bf3-b139-1429f8c51040\",\"source\":\"\",\"requesterFields\":\"\",\"type\":\"CUSTOMER\",\"status\":\"APPROVED\",\"lastUpdateTime\":\"1615130797664\"}}";

try
{
    var orgResp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetOrganizationResponse>(httpRespContent);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Unfortunately I can't change the input, it is a response from a remote service.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to escape the double quote with an escaped backslash which would result in your schemaFields looking like

```
"{\\\"main\\\":{\\\"city\\\":[\\\"cit...
```

Comment: That did it, used this site for help with escaping: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html#ad-output